# Not able to display server error in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, error-handling, server, next.js13

I have a server action code for signing up users

```
// Signup Server Action
export async function getSignupAction(params: signUpType) {

    const { name, email, password } = params

    const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    });

    if (existingUser && existingUser.email === email) {
        throw new Error("That email address is taken. Please try another.")
    }
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword
        }
    });

    return { success: true, newUser }
}
```

and we are throwing error like this

```
if (existingUser && existingUser.email === email) {
        throw new Error("That email address is taken. Please try another.")
}
```

it works fine in localhost

[image]

but when i deploy it vercel then it show this type of error

[image]

how to fix this?

Comment: repo link ---> https://github.com/sujjeee/nextauth-prisma-demo